# Take second value of tuple by first value

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I need to store second option of tuple (human-readable value | "Name A") to `name` variable. How to make it?

```
CHOICES = (
   ('A', 'Name A'),
   ('B', 'Name B'),
   ('C', 'Name C'),
)

if "first value" in CHOICES:
   name = "second value"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just convert your tuple to a `dict`:

```
>>> names = dict(CHOICES)
{'C': 'Name C', 'A': 'Name A', 'B': 'Name B'}
>>> name = names['A'] # If you're sure 'first value' is in CHOICES
>>> name
'Name A'
>>> name = names.get('D', 'No such name') # If you're not sure 'first value' is present
>>> name
'No such name'
```

Comment: Finally, I used your idea with little changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input like if not first value is present still tuple have least two item like this,

```
CHOICES = (
('A', 'Name A'),
('B', 'Name B'),
('', 'Name C'),
)'
```

This will create list of second option of tuple

```
name = dict(CHOICES).values()
```

Comment: Hello! I dont need list of all second values.In my application user enter first value, for example A, then I need to save 'Name A' to name variable. If first value "B" I need to save "Name B" to name variable. Do you have any ideas about that?